# I have a file with so many lines which needs find and replace in shell

Tags: regex, shell, vim

I have lines like

```
SC2268,Registration lauch causes a menu of what the user wants to do
```

I need to change this to

```
[SC2268]:Registration lauch causes a menu of what the user wants to do
```

I have tried the following things:

```
1.%s/\(\w\+\),\(\w\+\)/\[1]:\2/gi
2.%s/\(SC[0-9]*\)/\[1]/gi
```

But no luck.

Comment: Looks like your `\1` is "broken" (`\[1` is not the same)

Comment: Also, you seem to be escaping... everything. So you're literally looking for `(` followed by a word character followed by `),(` and so on.

Comment: Can u please correct my regex

Comment: I'm lazy, I'd do it this way: echo 'SC2268,Registration lauch causes a menu of what the user wants to do' | perl -pe 's/^/[/; s/,/]:/'
[SC2268]:Registration lauch causes a menu of what the user wants to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:%s/^\([^,]*\),/[\1]:/
```

looks reasonable to me (EDIT: Thanks @Sven for pointing out I needed to change the `,` into `:`)

Comment: I think the `:` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. The symbol to insert the first match is `\1`; the backslash must be directly before the number:

```
:%s/\(SC[0-9]*\)/[\1]/gi
```

The escaping and syntax of the `{pattern}` and `{replacement}` parts in `:s/{pattern}/{replacement}/` are different! When in doubt, please consult the help:

- `:help pattern`
- `:help s/\1`

Also note that there are shorter ways for this particular one; see (and try to understand) @bobbogo's answer.

Comment: You nailed it,I missed in escaping the charecter

Comment: I wonder what the shortest pattern is? It turns out that you need to change the `,` into `:` too (cheers @Sven), so I think your answer was probably on the right lines.